# CNTK Progress Printer

Tags: cntk

Can we better document what the different parameters for Progress Printer's constructor mean?

https://cntk.ai/pythondocs/cntk.utils.html#module-cntk.utils.progress_print

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This as been fixed. The documentation site will be updated with release 2.0 beta 8 or greater.